# MS SQL Loop within a loop

Tags: sql-server, loops, insert, cursor

I have two tables - one is called #final and has a lot of customer data (composite of all information). Dozen columns or so - `first_name, middle_name, last_name, address, attendees` etc. I've also got a second table

```
create table #diff_temp
(
customer_no int,
num_reception int,
num_guests int,
diff int
)
```

the way the second table is populated with a customer ID, total reception and guest tickets and the difference between `diff = reception-guests`

What I need to do is run a loop and insert name, address information into #final the amount of times that equals diff per record.

For example.

`#diff_Temp` has data that looks like this.

```
customer_no num_reception   num_guests  diff
1           5               1           4
2           12              10          2
3           3               1           2
4           32              20          12
5           12              10          2
6           8               6           2
```

What i need to happen is that there is a loop for customer 1 the loop runs 4 times and data is entered 4 times into `#final`. For customer 2 the loop will run 2 times, for customer 4 it will run 12 times, and so on.

For each customer the loop runs amount times of the value in the diff column. The loop then inserts data into #final based on a large sql query.

I can't seem to figure out how to make a cursor or loop work here.

---

This is the script I've got - it runs but doesn't do anything. 
When i run the internal cursor only it takes the amount of rows (6) and enters each row 6 times. Not what I want.

Newly updated script:

```
DECLARE @Iteration INT = 1      -- Loop
DECLARE @diff INT  = 1          -- Cursor
DECLARE @owner_customer_no INT  -- Cursor

BEGIN    
                DECLARE loop_cursor CURSOR FOR  
                SELECT owner_customer_no, diff 
                FROM #diff_temp 

                OPEN loop_cursor   
                FETCH NEXT FROM loop_cursor INTO @owner_customer_no, @diff   

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
                BEGIN  

                SET @Iteration = 1
                WHILE @Iteration <= @diff
                BEGIN     
                        insert into #final
                        select distinct 
                        e.customer_no,                          

                        0 as guest_cust_no,                 
                        h.fname,
                        ...
                        where   e.campaign_no = 1119
                        and sc.coding_scenario = 2

                PRINT @Iteration
                PRINT @diff
                PRINT @owner_customer_no

                SET @Iteration = @Iteration + 1
                END

                FETCH NEXT FROM loop_cursor INTO @owner_customer_no, @diff   
                END   

                CLOSE loop_cursor   
                DEALLOCATE loop_cursor
END
```

This code is generating the following

```
(6 row(s) affected)
iteration 1
diff 4
customer 1

(6 row(s) affected)
iteration 2
diff 4
customer 1

(6 row(s) affected)
iteration 3
diff 4
customer 1

(6 row(s) affected)
iteration 4
diff 4
customer 1

(6 row(s) affected)
iteration 1
diff 2
customer 2

(6 row(s) affected)
iteration 2
diff 2
customer 2
```

Each iteration/loop is inserting 6 rows - what i want it to do is insert 1 row.

Comment: Why do you think you can't figure it out?   What code did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: @TabAlleman - i tried, a few things that is where i am stuck. I've added the code into the question.

Comment: From what is posted there is no need for any looping at all here. This is just inserting data which can and should avoid loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare the variable `@diff`, its value is NULL.

Then you immediately try to use it in the loop:

```
DECLARE @diff INT, @owner_customer_no INT -- Cursor

WHILE @Iteration <= @diff
```

But since `@Iteration` is never "less than or equal to" NULL, the WHILE loop doesn't execute.

EDIT:   Actually, you need to move this loop:

```
WHILE @Iteration <= @diff
BEGIN
...
SET @Iteration = @Iteration + 1

END
```

to INSIDE your cursor, so that it executes for each of the rows in `#diff_temp`.

EDIT 2:

After this line,

```
FETCH NEXT FROM loop_cursor INTO @owner_customer_no, @diff
```

Set `@Iteration` back to 1, so that the inner loop will execute correctly for the next row from `#diff_temp`.

Comment: I've updated the @diff to start at 1 - the loop runs now but still inaccurately .

Comment: See my edit.  Put your outer loop inside the cursor, and put your INSERT inside of that.

Comment: I made the change, its running a very long time. I think i hit some kind of infinite loop. . ... Fetch the cursor, while fetch_status = 0, begin, while iteration <= diff, insert .... set iteration = iteration + 1, then fetch next value. ... why is running so long.

Comment: Edit your question and show the new code that is running long.   Maybe you accidentally deleted something important.

Comment: It needed begin/end in the loop. I added that and it ran -- and it seems to give me the correct data for printing. but something is still wrong -- a given customer ID has iteration amount of 4, it inserts all 6 rows in each iteration. Customer ID 1 gets 1 iteration with 6 customer records, a second iteration of all 6 customer records and so on. I'm updating the code momentarily.

Comment: Make sure that you are re-setting `@Iteration` back to 1 after the inner loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to describe in your comment, with this line:  "Customer ID 1 gets 1 iteration with 6 customer records, a second iteration of all 6 customer records and so on."   Can you edit your question with an example of what you are seeing?   And is the correct value for `@diff` getting printed each time?  Also, you should probably add an example of the results you actually want, because I just re-read your original question, and it sounds like you are getting exactly what you asked for, so maybe the original question wasn't clear.

Comment: I've added more to the question -- each iteration inserts 6 rows. I want it to insert 1 row. (Customer 1 has 24 rows instead of 4, and so on -- I have a total of 144 rows but I should have 24. 4 rows of the first account, 2 for the second, 2 for the third, 12 for the 4th etc.

Comment: I got it. I added another clause into my insert and it worked. Thank you.